Nginx reverse Proxy randomly throws error for "Already listening to port 80 & 443"
I have set up nginx as a reverse proxy for my app with LetsEncrypt as SSL. All goes smoothly, but sometimes all of a sudden nginx goes down with an error message:
Already bind with port 80/443

and a long list of similar messages. Whenever I restart manually - it works fine.
service nginx restart-all is back up and working.
My wild guess is that it could be Letsencrypt making that fail randomly. I have a very basic nginx proxy pass configuration with letsencrypt (certbot) settings added by certbot.
Currently, I have a Web status checker that notifies me whenever it goes down, and I manually restart it. But this is frustrating and I don't understand what is causing it.

sometimes - how much time is sometimes?

once or twice in a week

My wild guess is that it could be Letsencrypt making that fail randomly. what about a netstat at the time of the failure? Does that show anything?

once or twice in a week nah, letsencrypt doesn't work that way

I tried lsof -i :80 to see if any service running on port 80 or with 443, but no service is running and only letsencrypt has to do with port 80/443 for the SSL verification thing. Something is going fishy and the worst part, it is not 1 server but I have 127 servers and unfortunately - all of them have the issue.
